Помогите разобраться в чём ошибка?
Я ввёл команды как в книге, соблюдая все пробелы, и условия, но мне выдаёт ошибку, я не понимаю в чём дело. Код вводил в оболочке IDLE shell 3.11
x=100
    if x/2==50:
        print("да")
    if x*4!=4:
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    x=1000
    if x/4 ==25:
        print("да")
    if x*2>= 500:
    SyntaxError: multiple statements found while competing a single statement


Что-то не так с отступами.

Не очень понятно, что хотели этим сказать в книге, но вот работающий код:
x=100
if x/2==50:
    print("да")
if x*4!=4:
    x=1000
if x/4 ==25:
    print("да")
if x*2>= 500:
    pass#или любое другие действие заместо "pass"

